# Full-text search indexing only on certain rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, documents and revisions. Documents has two columns: document ID and title, and revisions has 3 columns: document ID, revision ID, body.

When I perform my full-text search against the body column of the revisions table, I'd only like to query against the latest revision. Is there a way to tell SQL Server to only index on rows for the latest revision of a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, there is no way to index only records with a specific id, but you can add the latest revision id to your query.

That can be done like adding:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  revisions r
WHERE
  /* Your r.body condition AND */
  r.revisionId = 
    (SELECT
      MAX(mr.revisionId) 
    FROM
      revisions mr 
    WHERE mr.documentid = r.documentid)
```

If you always need only to index the latest version, it may be better to add the body of that revision to the documents table or to another table that has a 1:1 relation to document. That way, each document has one indexed revision, while the others are stored for backup only. This is specifically useful if your documents have many revisions.

Comment: Thanks! I feel really dirty searching through all revisions and throwing out results for other revisions (not to mention, without knowing much about the algorithm it seems it may skew the overall rank results) so I guess for the time being I'll be storing the latest revisions in the document table, so the revisions table exists as more of an archive.